# Kong (0.10) API setup and usage

Tags: kong

I am new to Kong and am trying to get my hands dirty with Kong.
I have an environment where kong (0.10) and Cassandra (latest) run on separate docker containers. My OS is macOS -Sierra 10.12.4.

**Cassandra in docker**:

```
docker run -d --name kong-database -p 9042:9042 cassandra:latest
```

**Kong in docker**:

```
 docker run -d --name kong \
   --link kong-database:kong-database \
   -e "KONG_DATABASE=cassandra" \
   -e "KONG_CASSANDRA_CONTACT_POINTS=kong-database" \
   -e "KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database" \
   -p 8000:8000 \
   -p 8443:8443 \
   -p 8001:8001 \
   -p 7946:7946 \
   -p 7946:7946/udp \
   kong
```

As per the [Kong documentation](https://getkong.org/docs/0.10.x/getting-started/adding-your-api/), I added my first API (to get the IP) via Kong Admin API.

```
curl -i -X POST \
  --url http://localhost:8001/apis/ \
  --data 'name=example-api' \
  --data 'hosts=example.com' \
  --data 'upstream_url=http://httpbin.org/ip'
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Wed, 19 Apr 2017 23:39:13 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false
Server: kong/0.10.1

{"http_if_terminated":true,"id":"9bab7ba9-f1f2-4b4d-aa9d-9966da17f94b","retries":5,"preserve_host":false,"created_at":1492645153409,"upstream_connect_timeout":60000,"upstream_url":"http:\/\/httpbin.org\/ip","upstream_send_timeout":60000,"https_only":false,"upstream_read_timeout":60000,"strip_uri":true,"name":"example-api","hosts":["example.com"]}
```

When I execute the following command to test it,

```
curl -i -X GET --url http://localhost:8000/ --header 'Host: example.com'
```

I get this,

```
    HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND
Date: Wed, 19 Apr 2017 23:40:48 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 233
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.7.1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Via: kong/0.10.1
X-Kong-Upstream-Latency: 590
X-Kong-Proxy-Latency: 93

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

However, when i directly `curl http://httpbin.org/ip`, I get my IP.

How do I configure Kong to get the same result?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the upstream_url to `http://httpbin.org` and then the following curl Request:

```
curl -i -X GET --url http://localhost:8000/ip --header 'Host: example.com'
```

I got the same message today and found out, that it does not work, when you have a slash at the end. Maybe there is something, that produces this, when you add the API with this upstream_url.

Edit:
With your config, maybe the request should look like this:

```
curl -i -X GET --url http://localhost:8000 --header 'Host: example.com'
```

Please note the removed slash at the end of the url. Maybe this causes this Error and you can fix it, without having to edit your API Config :)

Answer (score 0):

your api you added has a name (example-api) which you did not specified in the test url

so it should be something like this:

curl -i -X GET --url http://localhost:8000/example-api --header 'Host: example.com'

Comment: I dont remember the necessity to specify the API Name explicitly in the Request URL

Comment: Matthias S, so how the kong proxy knows to what API to redirect your call? :)

Comment: I thought the Host Header is meant for this purpose. Or was there some breaking change in v10.x? I can send Requests through Kong without specifying the exact api in the request URL. Well, at least with 0.9.x. Also the Quick Start Guide does not reference this behaviour

Comment: ah yes, you can use host header as well
either one

Comment: Well, and I did'nt know, that I can specify the api in the Request URL, now we both learned something :-D